# Netstat shows programs running on different ports then they should

Tags: socket, netstat

I have some code I'm testing.  Program A listens on a predefined socket for program B to connect to and for my testing I'm running 32 instances of the programs A and B.  I've written my script to tell program A to listen to port 9001-9032 and put in the configuration files for each instance of program B the corresponding port to connect to.

When I run the script which starts up program A and B and run `netstat -tnap` I find that of all the ports 9001-9032 the only port actually used is 9001 which is used by another program (my mistake!).  When I grep for program A, I find each instance is listening on a seemingly completely random ports that have no relationship to the ports 90** they should be listening on.  However, my program B, which should be connecting to ports 9001-9032, is able to find and connect to each instance of program A despite A apparently not listening on the ports it's B should be trying to connect to. I'm rather confused as to how that's possible.

If that isn't confusing enough my 32 program and *only* the 32 one (listening on 9032) dies at startup with an error that the address was refused when it tries to bind to the port.  I tried changing the programs to listen on ports 15001-15032 just to see what would happen and I still got the exact same behavior; all programs seem to be listening on random ports and the 32 program can't establish a connection.

Can anyone explain why my ports are behaving the way the are?  Am I misunderstanding some part of netstat or Linux ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to simulate the allegedly broken connections with `socat` (a command line tool that establish arbitrary byte streams).

Try to listen on the ports with

```
socat - TCP-Listen:9001
```

for a tcp connection that listens on port 9001 or

```
socat - UDP-Listen:9001
```

for a udp connection.

Examine if `netstat -p` (or alternatively `sockstat`) shows the connection that `socat` established. If so, you should investigate your code further and maybe post a source code related question on [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

In the other case, please let us know!